# Inset Box Shadow Gets Hidden On Filling Rect

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am having a canvas and there is an inset box shadow. However, the box shadow is well shown but on calling fillRect at every time using requestAnimationFrame, it gets hidden.

I tried to again set the box shadow after fillrect but still got not good results

Here is a codepen link: https://codepen.io/asiancat54x/pen/ExXNLzj

Here is the snippet

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const c = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.width = innerWidth

canvas.height = innerHeight

function a(){
  c.fillRect(0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height)
  
  canvas.boxShadow = "box-shadow: inset 0 0 60px 5px red, 3px 3px 5px 0 red;"

  requestAnimationFrame(a)
}

a()
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #2e3440;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 60px 5px red,
    3px 3px 5px 0 red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
This is with a div element

<div class="header"></div>

Cannot create such box shadow on canvas

<br>

<canvas class="header"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just an observation as it does not cure your problem, the syntax of the resetting of the box-shadow on the canvas is wrong. It needs to change the canvas style: canvas.style.boxShadow = "inset 0 0 60px 5px red, 3px 3px 5px 0 red;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why Inset Box Shadow on canvas doesn't work.

But I quickly created a hack. See if this works for you. It basically draws a DIV as well as canvas with DIV over the canvas having transparent background but a box shadow.
https://codepen.io/hariom_balhara/pen/RwgoJRQ

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const c = canvas.getContext("2d")
c.fillStyle='green'
canvas.width = innerWidth

canvas.height = innerHeight

function a(){
  c.fillRect(0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height)
  
  canvas.boxShadow = "box-shadow: inset 0 0 60px 5px red, 3px 3px 5px 0 red;"

  requestAnimationFrame(a)
}

a()
```

```css
.header {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #2e3440;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 60px 5px red,
    3px 3px 5px 0 red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
This is with a div element



Cannot create such box shadow on canvas

<br>
<div style="position:relative">
  <div class="header" style="z-index:1;background:transparent"></div>
  <canvas class="header">  </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, this answer surely works. Thanks. +1 vote and Accepted Solution :)